# What is the PEG ratio? How is the PEG ratio calculated? How is the PEG ratio useful for stock investing?

Tags: investing, stocks, ratio

What is the PEG ratio?  How is the PEG ratio calculated?  How is the PEG ratio useful for stock investing?  Are higher or lower PEG values better for a stock - and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PEG is **Price/Earnings to Growth**.  It is calculated as [Price/Earnings](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/price-earningsratio.asp)/[Annual EPS Growth](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/eps.asp).  It represents how good a stock is to buy, factoring in growth of earnings, which P/E does not.  Obviously when PEG is lower, a stock is more undervalued, which means that it is a better buy, and more likely to go up.

---

**Additional References:**

- [How Useful Is the PEG Ratio?](http://www.fool.com/investing/value/2006/04/06/how-useful-is-the-peg-ratio.aspx) - The Motley Fool
- [PEG Ratio Nails Down Value Stocks](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/analyst/043002.asp) - Investopedia
- [Yahoo Finance Stock Screener](http://screen.yahoo.com/stocks.html) (Allows screening by PEG)

Answer (score 2):

PEG is Price to Earnings Growth.  I've forgotten how it's calculated, I just remember that a PEG ratio of 1-2 is attractive by Graham & Dodd standards.